# Can gulp collect lines grep:ed into single output file?

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-concat

I'm trying to filter out lines from all .js source files, and put into a separate file. (Specifically, I'm trying to grep all calls to a string translation function and post-process them).

I think I have the different parts figured out but can't make them fit together.

1. For each file, process it
2. Write each file's grep:ed lines to output.
3. Append the result to a file

I've tried to `through.push(<output per file>)` from the plugin, but the following step expects a file, not a string.

From there, I expect I could do something like gulp-concat or stream merge on the results and pipe it on to `gulp.dist`, but there's bit missing here.

Comment: Please post the relevant code that you've written so far.

Comment: Sorry, came back to this a lot later. I figured it out, I just didn't work with the file object correctly. Thanks for offering to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way - simply replace the Vinyl file's `content` with the lines to output, and push that through to `through.push`.